# Views - group/aggregate by field with multiple content types

Tags: entities, views

I currently have a block view that I am using as an index. I have 2 content types that I am displaying in this block, and these are grouped together by their type, as an unformatted list of fields. The types are not displaying the same field.

The second content type needs to be grouped further, as they represent items relating to the same thing which will be displayed together on the page.

I am struggling to perform the second grouping. I have tried the unformatted list settings and adding in a second group, but that removes the items for the first group. I have also tried playing with aggregation and the query distinct settings, but that doesn't seem to do anything. I have also tried the Views Distinct module, also with no success.

**Edit:** It's the *value* of the field that's duplicated.

What I've got:

```
*Group1
    -Title1
    -Title2
*Group2
    -FieldValue1
    -FieldValue1
    -FieldValue1
    -FieldValue2
    -FieldValue2
```

What I would like:

```
*Group1
    -Title1
    -Title2
*Group2
    -FieldValue1
    -FieldValue2
```

Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the default **Views attachment display** so you can have different queries and/or fields next to each other.
[image: Views attachment display]